# Can any category be imbedded in a balanced category?

Tags: category-theory

It is a simple fact that any retract is an epimorphism, and that in a sub-category a retract preserves its epic property (the same for co-retract and monomorphism).

My question is: is the only reason that a epimorphism fails to be a retract is the "cutting out" of its left inverse from some "bigger" category?
Or are there other problems?

If this is the only problem, it means that we could "enlarge" the category, making each monic+epic a retract+co-retract and a isomorphism in the "bigger" category ,and then also an isomorphism in the original.
Or in other words, there is an imbedding into a balanced category.

Comment: Since there exist morphisms that are both epimorphisms and monomorphisms which are not isomorphisms, it follows that your idea doesn't work. One reason is, that an embedding doesn't necessarily preserve epimorphisms or monomorphisms, nor does it necessarily reflect isomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every presheaf category is balanced, so the Yoneda embedding does the job.

Comment: Although note that this embedding doesn't preserve epis! The maps which become epis in the Yoneda embedding are the split epis. So this embedding works not by adjoining left inverses but by making it much harder to be an epi.

Comment: I guess I answered the question in the title but went against the spirit of the body of the post, @Qiaochu.

Comment: Would either of you know of a reference for this fact, that presheaf categories are balanced?  I believe I know a proof, but it would be more convenient to have a reference.